# Having trouble understanding Hilbert polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am studying hilbert polynomial from this note: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~stevmatt/hilbert_polynomials.pdf

In particular, example 1:

> Let $X=\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}\subset \mathbb{P}^2_k$ be 3 distinct points, then $$h_X(1)=\dim_k(k[X_0,X_1,X_2]/I(X))_1= \dim_k(k[X_0,X_1,X_2]_1)-\dim(I(X)_1).$$
>   The ideal $I(X)_1$ consists of all homogeneous linear polynomials vanishing at $p_1,p_2,p_3$,

then I don't understand why we can conclude:

> $\dim_k(I(X)_1)=1$ when $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are collinear and $0$ otherwise.

How can we see this?

Comment: Homogeneous linear polynomials on $\Bbb P^2$ correspond (up to scaling) with lines in $\Bbb P^2$.

Comment: @KReiser Ah I see, this is very easy! Thanks!